# JAXB how to marshall ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>

Tags: xml, jaxb

I got an attribute like this

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Vector3D>>    trajectories = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Vector3D>>();
```

Vector3D is a simple container for 3 double values.
How do I marshall this properly with JAXB? I only get  elements in the XML-File.

Comment: Have a look at this, perhaps it's related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254948/soap-response-wrongly-deserializing-as-null-in-cxf-simple-frontend-aegis-dat/9921501#9921501

Comment: Also, I suggest you use the interfaces rather than concrete types: `private List<List<Vector3D>> trajectories = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Vector3D>>()`

Comment: mh, thanks, but this solution doesn't work for here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)**  Use

```
private ArrayList<ListOfVectors>    trajectories = new ArrayList<ListOfVectors>();
```

instead of

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Vector3D>>    trajectories = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Vector3D>>();
```

where `ListOfVectors` is

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ListOfVectors 
{
   ArrayList<Vector3D> list = new ArrayList<Vector3D>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137665/how-do-i-get-cxf-to-understand-a-mapstring-listmybean helped me